# Elm filter a list with input String

Tags: string, list, filter, compare, elm

I have model

```
   type alias Model =
    { 
      url : String
    , devices : List Device
    , input : String
    , isFilter : Bool
    , deviceSuggestion : Maybe Device
    }

type alias Device =
    { 
      status : String
    , license_plate : String
    , device_id : String
    }
```

This is how i update the data but i have no idea how to do for filter after i type something in the search box

```
update msg model =
case msg of
    GotResult result ->
        case result of
            Ok devices ->
                ( { model | devices = devices }, portDevice devices )

            Err devices ->
                ( { model | error = Just "Error" }, Cmd.none )

    Tick _ ->
        ( model, fetchUrl )

    InputChange newInput ->
         ( { model | input = newInput //function filter here?}, Cmd.none)
        
    SearchFunction ->
        ({ model | input = "" }, toJS model.input)
```

This is my rendering View

```
renderPosts : Model -> Html Msg
    renderPosts model =
    div []
        [ h3 [] [ text "Filter List" ] ,
        , input [ type_ "text"
                , placeholder "Searching for devices"
                , onInput InputChange
                , value model.input
                , id "inputDevices"
                ] []
         --, checkListFunction model //check and filter list function here as well?
         , button [ onClick SearchFunction , id "searchDevice"] [ text "Search" ]
         ,
            div []
            ([ text "Device List" ] ++ List.map (\device -> renderPost device) model.devices) //display function
            ]
```

I want the output is like when i type the 1234 in searchbox then it detects and filter the below list with the license_plate in devices list.

**I tried the list.filter but it allows compare list to list.
**I tried String.contains but i need 2 strings. It gives error because input box is String and license_plate is List

Any help is appreciate...
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp <<< Example of output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example of modifying your `renderPosts` function with a `filteredDevices` binding, showing how you could apply the filter:

```
renderPosts : Model -> Html Msg
renderPosts model =
    let
        filteredDevices =
            List.filter (\device => String.contains model.input device.license_plate) model.devices
    in
    div []
        [ h3 [] [ text "Filter List" ] ,
            ...
            div []
            ([ text "Device List" ] ++ List.map (\device -> renderPost device) filteredDevices)
            ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @glennsl but i still got the errors
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^This `filteredDevices` value is a:    List { a | license_plate : String } -> List { a | license_plate : String }But `map` needs the 2nd argument to be:    List Device

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot the argument specifying which list to filter on! Fixed in the answer.

Comment: There may be other errors too though. I (obviously) haven't run this through the compiler or anything. It's just to give you an idea of how to do it.